# Excel VLOOKUP issue

Tags: vlookup, microsoft-excel-365

Why does my VLOOKUP return 5 instead of 1

[image]

And to show it's selecting the correct cells

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(G1, $A$9:$B$11,2,1)
```

Why is it returning 5 instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last parameter of your VLOOKUP, you are using 1, which is equivalent to TRUE, which tells VLOOKUP to use an approximate match. Change it to 0 or FALSE.