# Microsoft Excel - SUM cell that counts how many times conditions A B and C are found

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to work on a timesheet to find how many hours staff work per week, and make it neat and compact.

I have organised shifts into E, L, and EL, meaning early, late, and early&late.

I need to find a formula that will count the cell range, and for every time it reads E, add 6, every time it reads L, add 5, and every time it reads EL, add 12. I don't know if it's possible to do it in one cell, but I can't think of a way to do this even in multiple cells.

I tried to use a lookup as per [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/135739/how-do-i-assign-a-number-value-to-a-non-numerical-value-in-excel) which returned #VALUE, and it wouldn't count a sum either. I thought maybe I could nest a bunch of `IF` statements in one another, but then I couldn't find a way to sum. Every time it appeared in the search, it found one instance and that was it. I figure it'd be easier to explain the problem if I knew what I was doing! Sadly I don't.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Edit your question, and add a sample data and the expected result(s). Also add what you have already tried.

Comment: I had tried to use a lookup as per [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/135739/how-do-i-assign-a-number-value-to-a-non-numerical-value-in-excel) which returned #VALUE, and it wouldn't count a sum either.

I thought maybe I could nest a bunch of if statements in one another, but then I couldn't find a way to sum every time it appeared in the search, it found one instance and that was it. 

I figure it'd be easier to explain the problem if I knew what I was doing! Sadly I don't.

Comment: I have updated the question with the comment you gave. Check if I have not missed anything.

Comment: You will want to look into the following functions: sum.if, count

Comment: @AkaneTsuzura,, better add some sample data from the sheet currently you are working with, help us to fix the issue !!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but I think I found a good enough answer to the problem.

On a second tab, specify the values, such as [This](http://puu.sh/FZuPV/21074a8f07.png),
In a third tab, nesting a bunch of IF statements to check the same cell in sheet one for E, L, or EL, and using the values in tab two, return a number. I used

```
=IF(Sheet1!B2="E", Sheet2!$B$2, IF(Sheet1!B2="L", Sheet2!$B$3, IF(Sheet1!B2="EL", Sheet2!$B$4, 0)))
```

And then the rest was a simple sum, followed by referencing the sum cell on sheet 1 so that any other users of the spreadsheet wouldn't have to dig into sheet two or three and potentially break what I had going.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume your data is organize as follow (I know big assumption from my side):

- Column A: contains data about employees names
- Rows B1 to ...: have the shift dates (I stopped after only 3 dates on the image below)
- Rows B2 to ...: have the shift codes E, L or EL

I have a lookup table for each value of shift codes with an empty value set at 0. On column E, the sum/count based on the shift code. So on E2, the formula could be:

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(B2:D2,$B$14:$B$17,$C$14:$C$17))
```

What the formula does is to check the shift code of selected range `B2:D2` on the lookup table, returns their values and sum them.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I had just come to a very similar answer myself actually! I didnt leave the tables on page one just to avoid any confusion for anyone in the company who isnt familiar with excel. I don't fully understand a lot of excel functions, and I've never used XLookup before, but it looks to be a more streamlined version of what I have!

Comment: @AkaneTsuzura XLOOKUP is among the new functions introduce since last year. If you are using Office365, it should be available to you. If not, you can combine INDEX, MATCH to achieve the same results.